# Wifi connects for sometimes then disconnects and then never connects

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

Their is a big issue of WiFi in my phone when i first bought it...

My phone is a **Spice Stellar Mi-439, Android KITKAT v4.4.2, 1GHz Processor, 512RAM, 4GB Internal, currently 16GB Expandable.**

The problem is that Wifi connects when i switch ON the Wifi and enter the WiFi network but disconnects after sometime of browsing and never connects again even by switch the WiFi ON-OFF-ON and not even by disabling Data Connection. Neither it disconnects when in Sleep or StandBy Mode, it disconnects during browsing or any time. Whereas other users on that WiFi network don't complain about any issue like that. I have no control over that WiFi Network.

It only works when i reboot the set but again disconnects after sometime.

I didn't got any solution from internet for it.

Any knowledge about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the solution for it but i found an app that automatically fix this issue without rebooting the phone...

[WifiFixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer&hl=en)

Hope this works for people having issues with wifi...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been testing one of my app on spice stellar phones. The problem seems to be with the phones as the Mac ID keeps changing (yes, that right). It starts with a specific Mac and then suddenly the Mac ID exposed to the network changes and the phone is dropped from the network. If I Forget the wifi connection and reconnect, the same behaviour is observed at random intervals.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply... So, have you got any solution for this, could this be resolved or not???

Comment: No buddy, only the developers who ported android on this model or just the wifi stack can fix the issue. In all probability spice doesn'the even have a team to do that. Most of the low cost mobile phones from these companies are straight pick ups of assembled pieces from China with their branding on top. I am not very sure about spice though. Long and short of it, buy another, Intex aqua Y (y something model) in the same price range is a better pick so far as performance and reliability is concerned.

Comment: ok, i can admire your anwser, bad luck for me... Thanks for the answer...

Comment: hi @Bhasar could you tell me which app you uploaded to test Mac ID of the phone???

Comment: If that's the culprit, I might have a work-around: one of those [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) apps could be used to either periodically drop and re-establish the connection, or even check when that's needed (e.g. by monitoring the MAC address) and acting such only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

What type of wifi network it is? Office, Institutional or personal home network?
Have you tested your phone for different wifi connection other than the one on which you are trying to connect now. If not test it. This would at least let you know where your problem lies whether the wifi router or your handset.

Comment: Thanks for reply @rajat, well its an Office Wifi network, i havent connecting to any other wifi network but i have tested my wifi with wifi hotspot, i didnt know where the problem lies...

Comment: Did it work on hotspot? And on which device did you tether hotspot?

Comment: yes, it works on hotspot unstoppable, i have tested it via Samsung Galaxy...

Comment: This conclusion is drawn as your phones wifi works perfectly with hotspot or other network. So there should be some problem with the WIFI provided by you company and your phone. May be you have to register and get some space for your device in the network ( IP ). Try to contact the Network Administer of your company. Many a times there are proxy networks, firewall installed in wifis provided in private organisations.

Answer (score 0):

How far are you from the Wi-Fi router?
You might get disconnected, because you are simply too far.
I've made some measurements and from my experience, devices have different network detection ranges - my tablet disconnects when I'm 6 meters away from the router, mobile phone - 12 meters and laptop - 20 meters.

Comment: well, for this i have installed Wifi Analyser App previously, it always shows strong signal...

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your phone dialer
2. Dial *#0011#
3. When you see the "ServiceMode" screen, press the left menu button
4. Select "WiFi"
5. See that "Wifi Power Save Mode" button that is "ON" - well turn it "OFF"
6. Exit this menu, turn off your Wifi and turn it back on.

   - If you already entered all your wifi credentials, forget your network info (remove it) and re-enter it again.

   This should fix your problem. Had the same problem with my S4 but it's fixed now.

Comment: Hi @LucasVL7, the second step is not working on my phone, it says **"Connection problem or invalid MMI code"**...

Comment: Oh excuse me. I think it's an Samsung related code then. Thought it was a default code.

Comment: any alternative idea about this u have???

Comment: No man, I'm sorry